# Reading specific lines not working [Python 3]

Tags: python-3.x

I found a topic showing how to print out specific lines from a text file , but when I try it on my code , it does not do anything , I indented the code properly , but it still doesn't do anything.(last lines from `if GTIN ==86947367:`)

```
while True:
    itemsneeded = input("How many items do you need?")
    if itemsneeded.isnumeric() and int(itemsneeded) <= 5:
        break
    GTIN = ''

count = 0

while count < int(itemsneeded):
    GTIN = (input('Please enter all GTIN-8 for all items'))

    if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN) == 8:
        Num0 = int(GTIN[0]) * 3
        Num1 = int(GTIN[1])
        Num2 = int(GTIN[2]) * 3
        Num3 = int(GTIN[3])
        Num4 = int(GTIN[4]) * 3
        Num5 = int(GTIN[5])
        Num6 = int(GTIN[6]) * 3
        Num7 = int(GTIN[7])
        total2 = (Num0 + Num1 + Num2 + Num3 + Num4 + Num5 + Num6 + Num7)

        if total2 % 10 == 0:
            print(GTIN)
            if GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
                print('entered GTIN is valid')
            else:
                print('The code entered is invalid')
                print('Please renter this code')

        count += 1
    else:
        print("The entered GTIN-8 codes are incorrect")

if GTIN == 86947367:
    fp = open("read_it.txt")
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 1:
            print(line)
        elif i == 2:
            print(line)
    fp.close()
```

Use the text file if you want to test , for items needed, put 2 and for the GTIN codes put `86947367`both times.
https://mega.nz/#!GQ0BhTKD!KsC4ZhFW7LJuwXXkJFyjdS9geiiJjaoUy6CAbuD6qkI

I also tried:

```
f = open('read_it.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

print(lines[1])
print(lines[2])
```

But when I added `if GTIN == 86947367:` , it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
if GTIN == "86947367":
```

Due to the fact that when you read data from a file or input, it will be in string format until you reformat it to an int or other.

Comment: you are a life saver ! :))))